# How can I see a graph of commits on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way of seeing a `git tree` command on GitHub?

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a project's home page, click on Insights then Network, and it will show the history graph.

For example: https://github.com/git/git/network. Change `git/git` with your project path.

Direct link: https://github.com/**path-to-project**/network

Comment: GitHub only allows this on public repos or private repos in a paid plan, showing the following message if you don't meet these criteria: "Upgrade to GitHub Team or make this repository public to enable this feature."

Comment: Explaining in "UI mode": Go to the projects home page, click on "Insights" tab, then click on "Network" tab in the left side panel, and it will show the history graph.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub doesn't support directly executing git commands from within GitHub. You will have to clone the repo to your machine and use the git commands (like git log) from that machine.

But if you just want the graph, there is a work around using browser extension.

[image: Le git graph demo]

Install the extension from here : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/le-git-graph-commits-grap/joggkdfebigddmaagckekihhfncdobff

It will add a new "commits" section to every GitHub repo you open. Open the commits graph and there, all commits across branches will be listed along with the git graph.

[image: Le git graph demo 2]

Hope it helps!

Comment: well im not about to authorize add some scetchy tool into my workplace.

Comment: The whole extension is open sourced. It is only as sketchy as any other tool you could find. But yeah, this is in an early stage and it is up to your discretion to go for it or stay away.